# passing the password for sudo permission in subprocess Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

For example, take a simple program

```
from subprocess import check_output
t = check_output(['ls', '-a'])
print t
```

now there are many commands which needs to be run with sudo permission. for given example

```
from subprocess import check_output
t = check_output(['sudo', 'ls', '-a'])
print t
```

but it asks for password in my terminal. instead I want to input the password programatically, even bypass this, if possible.

Comment: You're going to need to use `pexpect`, not `subprocess` for this, because sudo doesn't read from stdin, instead, it interacts directly with the terminal. See the question I linked to in the comment above.

Comment: You can bypass password security through entries in [`/etc/sudoers`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).